# Azure pipeline conditionally set pool

Tags: azure-pipelines

```
name: $(Build.BuildId)-${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName']}}

pool:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
    name: 'Default' # run on rwb's machine (plus whatever else is in the default pool).
  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest' # run on the MS hosted pool (limited to 1800 hours per month).

variables:
  -name: isHosted
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
    value: false
  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
    value: true
```

but

```
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 4, Col: 3): A template expression is not allowed in this context
/azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 6, Col: 3): A template expression is not allowed in this context
```

It's also a mess having to repeat the conditions.

Can this be made to work?

**Update**

Tidied this up. Had to add a job, irritatingly. The variable seems to be getting set correctly, but the job always runs on the Hosted Agent;
the condition `${{ if eq(variables.useSelfHostedAgent, 'True') }}` is ignored but the condition `${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}` works!
(This makes no sense -- which seems to be normal for Azure pipeline YML.)

```
name: $(Build.BuildId)-${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName']}}

variables:
  useSelfHostedAgent: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge')]

trigger:
- '*'

###############################################################################

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: AzurePipelineTemplates
      type: git
      name: AzurePipelineTemplates/AzurePipelineTemplates

jobs:
- job: Product
  pool:
    #${{ if eq(variables.useSelfHostedAgent, 'True') }}: # is ignored
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
      name: 'Default' # run on rwb's machine (plus whatever else is in the default pool).
    ${{ else }}:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' # run on the MS hosted pool (limited to 1800 hours per month).

  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Condition
    condition: eq(variables.useSelfHostedAgent, 'True')
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
          Write-Host "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party."

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Get pool name
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
          Write-Host "Agent.Name is $(Agent.Name)"
          Write-Host "useSelfHostedAgent is $(useSelfHostedAgent)"
      
  - template: BuildTestPackPublish.yml@AzurePipelineTemplates
    parameters:
      projectsToTest: '**/Company.Product.Tests.csproj'# Not SeleniumTests.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.

`-name: isHosted` should be `- name: isHosted`

Comment: The hours I must have lost counting whitespace in yml -- it's such rubbish.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough The Azure Pipelines YAML editor in VS Code is pretty good about highlighting simple syntax errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

From the warning information, it seems like it isn't allowed if the pool definition is higher up(e.g. at pipeline level) but it works fine if the pool definition is inside a job definition.

You can use `else` expression to replace   `${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}` that keeps your code simple.

For example:

```
jobs: 
- job: example
  pool:
      ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge') }}:
        name:  'Default' 
      ${{ else }}:
        vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

BTW you can use `Use parameters in pipelines` to select which pool you want to run.

Please refer to doc:[Use parameters in pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-in-pipelines)

**UPDATE**

> the condition ${{ if eq(variables.useSelfHostedAgent, 'True') }} is ignored

Because you define the variable `useSelfHostedAgent` as runtime expressions,runtime expressions can be used in variables and conditions. It can't be recognized in if expression.
Please refer to doc:[Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages)

Comment: It appears to be complicated by needing to set _either_ `name` (for self hosted) _or `vminage` (for hosted).

Comment: @RichardBarraclough updated the answer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: So it can't be made to work because there are lots of different and incompatible ways of having variables and `if`s?

Comment: Yes, i mean Compile time expressions can be used anywhere; runtime expressions can be used in variables and conditions.Please refer to doc[Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  pool:
    ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'), false) }}:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' # Always build master on the MS hosted pool (limited to 1800 hours per month).
    ${{ else }}:
      name: 'Default' 
      ${{ if or(and(parameters.symbols, ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'merge')), parameters.migrations) }}:
        demands: 
        - Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT # PushSymbols task in pack.yml only works on Windows.
```

It is impossible to use `Build.BuildId` in the `${{ if`.